# County the frequency of the same words in the same column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, word-frequency

I'm trying to analyse information in the Forbes top 2000 companies 2017 data set.

In the data set there is a column called country which represents the country of origin for each company in the data set. I would like to scan the column to find which countries have a compony in the top 2000. Then count how many companies each of those countries have in the top 2000 list. Therefore resulting in a table showing country and count.

e.g. output:

```
Country       Count
USA             756
China           564
Japan           267
England         100
Sweden           45 
...             ...
```

Not quite sure how to achieve this in R.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you give an example of what the data set is like? So in theory, you can just do table (df$country) where df is your data.frame and country is the column with the countries

Comment: top_countries<-Forbes_global %>% group_by(Country) %>% tally() %>% arrange(desc(n))

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

here is the rank for the forbes top 20 2017 from german wikipedia

```
library(rvest)

url<-"https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbes_Global_2000"

# Return a data frame
Forbes_global = url  %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_node(xpath = '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[15]') %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)

Forbes_global<-Forbes_global[1:25,]
```

here is the data

```
> head(Forbes_global)
  Rang                       Name Logo                                    Land Umsatz (Mrd. $) Gewinn  (Mrd. $) Aktiva (Mrd. $) Marktwert (Mrd. $)
1   1.                       ICBC      China Volksrepublik Volksrepublik China           151,4             42,0          3473,2              229,8
2   2.    China Construction Bank      China Volksrepublik Volksrepublik China           134,2             35,0          3016,6              200,5
3   3.         Berkshire Hathaway        Vereinigte Staaten Vereinigte Staaten           222,9             24,1           620,9              409,9
4   4.             JPMorgan Chase        Vereinigte Staaten Vereinigte Staaten           102,5             24,2          2513,0              306,6
5   5.                Wells Fargo        Vereinigte Staaten Vereinigte Staaten            97,6             21,9          1943,4              274,4
6   6. Agricultural Bank of China      China Volksrepublik Volksrepublik China           115,7             27,8            2816              149,2
       Branche
1       Banken
2       Banken
3 Mischkonzern
4       Banken
5       Banken
6       Banken
```

here is the output:

```
rank<-Forbes_global %>% group_by(Land) %>% tally() %>% arrange(desc(n))

> rank
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  Land                                        n
  <chr>                                   <int>
1 Vereinigte Staaten Vereinigte Staaten      13
2 China Volksrepublik Volksrepublik China     7
3 Deutschland Deutschland                     1
4 Frankreich Frankreich                       1
5 Japan Japan                                 1
6 Korea Sud Südkorea                          1
7 Niederlande Niederlande                     1
```

directly form wikipedia:

```
url<-"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbes_Global_2000"

top_countries = url  %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_node(xpath = '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[3]') %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)

top_countries$Companies<-gsub( "\\*","",top_countries$Companies)
```

output

```
> top_countries
   Rank                               Country Companies
1     1 United States (Including Puerto Rico)       525
2     2          China  (Including Hong Kong)       315
3     3                                 Japan       225
4     4       United Kingdom (including BOTS)        95
5     5    Germany  (Including Liechtenstein)        95
6     6           France  (Including DOM-TOM)        90
7     7                                 India        75
8     8                           South Korea        65
9     9             Canada (Excluding Québec)        65
10   10                             Indonesia        40
11   11                          Saudi Arabia        35
12   12                             Australia        35
13   13                                Sweden        20
14   14                                 Italy        20
15   15                                Russia        20
16   16                                 Spain        20
17   17                           Netherlands        20
18   18                                Turkey        20
19   19                               Ireland        18
20   20                                Brazil        18
21   21                              Thailand        16
22   22                          South Africa        12
23   23                               Denmark        12
24   24                              Malaysia        12
25   25                                Mexico        12
26   26                                Israel        11
27   27                             Singapore        11
28   28                               Algeria        11
29   29                  United Arab Emirates        11
30   30                               Belgium        10
31   31                                Norway        10
32   32                                 Chile        09
33   33                               Finland        09
34   34                                  Oman        07
35   35                               Austria        06
36   36                                 Qatar        06
37   37                                Taiwan        06
38   38                              Colombia        06
39   39                                Poland        06
40   40                           Philippines        05
41   41                              Portugal        05
42   42 Morocco  (Excluding & Including SADR)        05
43   43                               Vietnam        05
44   44                                 Libya        05
45   45                                Kuwait        04
46   46                             Argentina        03
47   47                               Nigeria        03
48   48                               Lebanon        02
49   49                                  Peru        02
50   50                                Greece        02
51   51                               Hungary        02
52   52                             Venezuela        02
53   53                                Cyprus        01
54   54                        Czech Republic        01
55   55                                Jordan        01
56   56                            Kazakhstan        01
57   57                                 Kenya        01
```

Comment: Thank you for all the help!!

Comment: Glad i could help, please consider to mark the question as solved using the green check image besides the answer.